# ManyToMany field point to self wrong behavior?

Tags: django, django-models

I am having the following lines in my model :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user_favorites = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name='Favorites', 
   blank=True)
```

What I am doing here is simple. I have a UserProfile object, each user have a list of users he favorites. this list is the user_favorites field.

I am accessing my field via Admin to add new favorites to the user. however, the behavior I see is that each time I am adding a user (via admin) to that specific user I see that the user I have favorite also has the user added him added to its user_favorites field.

So I want to make user X favorite Y and what happens is user X favorite Y and user Y favorite X. which was not what I intended.

Am I doing something wrong ? or maybe many to many to self is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong,I'm not sure if it's a bug of django,The solution is simplely change:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user_favorites = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name='Favorites', 
   blank=True)
```

to

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user_favorites = models.ManyToManyField('user.UserProfile', verbose_name='Favorites', 
   blank=True)
```

`user` is your appname of model `UserProfile`

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for many-to-many fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) explains this. By default, M2Ms on self are symmetrical - if I am your friend, you are my friend. To remove this behaviour, set `symmetrical=False`:

```
user_favorites = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, verbose_name='Favorites', blank=True)
```